# Scrolling break transform css on MS edge

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-transforms, microsoft-edge

I have a flipping `div` on button click.
On this flipped div, i have a scrolling list.

- If list is not scrolling (because not enough items), everything work
  good.
- But, if list i scrolling, items disappear...

Problem does not appear on Chrome and Safari browsers.
I think it's a compatibility problem with `transform animation`, but i'm not sure.

I reproduce this problem on this codepen : http://codepen.io/glalloue/pen/JbNZPK (or on snippet behind).
To test it, try to remove 2 items on the list, and it's working...if you put 4 items, everyhthing is broken.

Any idea to solve it ?

```js
document.getElementById("btn-front").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("flip").className = "flipped";
});

document.getElementById("btn-back").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("flip").className = "";
});
```

```css
#flip {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transition: transform 1s;
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform-origin: 150px 150px 0;
}

#front {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 2px);
}

#back {
  background-color: green;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 1px) rotateY(180deg);
}
#back .button {
  margin: 25px 50px 25px 50px;
}

.tile {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 75px 50px;
}

#flip.flipped {
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotateY(-180deg);
}

#list {
  height: 120px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="flip">
  <div id="front" class="tile">
    <button id="btn-front" class="button">Go to back</button>
  </div>
  <div id="back" class="tile">
    <button id="btn-back" class="button">Go to front</button>
    <div id="list">
      <div class="item">item 1</div>
      <div class="item">item 2</div>
      <div class="item">item 3</div>
      <div class="item">item 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of `backface-visibility: hidden;`, as you are giving `background` to `#back` `backface` won't visible. So you can remove `backface-visibility: hidden;`

```
.tile {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  /*backface-visibility: visible;*/
}
```

```js
document.getElementById("btn-front").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("flip").className = "flipped";
});

document.getElementById("btn-back").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("flip").className = "";
});
```

```css
#flip {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform-origin: 150px 150px 0;
}
#front {
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 2px);
}
#back {
  background-color: green;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 1px) rotateY(180deg);
}
#back .button {
  margin: 25px 50px 25px 50px;
}
.tile {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
.button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 75px 50px;
}
#flip.flipped {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotateY(-180deg);
}
#list {
  height: 120px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="flip">
  <div id="front" class="tile">
    <button id="btn-front" class="button">Go to back</button>
  </div>
  <div id="back" class="tile">
    <button id="btn-back" class="button">Go to front</button>
    <div id="list">
      <div class="item">item 1</div>
      <div class="item">item 2</div>
      <div class="item">item 3</div>
      <div class="item">item 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek Pandey, your answer is right in this case, but make some troubles in iOS (safari). 
I'm not sure remove "backface-visibility" is the solution in every cases. Do you mean that this property is not supported in MS Edge?

Comment: Perhaps this property is not supported in MS Edge, but you can use `vendor-prefixes` for safari and other browsers, except MS Edge.